# Post title incorrect in the foreach loop but content is correct - Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

```
function quotes_shortcode() {
    if ( false === ( $quotes = get_transient( 'random_quote' ) ) ) {
        // It wasn't there, so regenerate the data and save the transient

        $args = array(
         'post_type' => 'quotes',
         'orderby'   => 'rand',
         'fields' => 'id',
         'posts_per_page' => '1'
        );

        $quotes = get_posts( $args );
        //Now we store the array for one day.
        //Just change the last parameter for another timespan in seconds.
        $seconds_until_next_day = strtotime('tomorrow') - time();
        set_transient( 'random_quote', $quotes, MINUTE_IN_SECONDS );
    }

        foreach ( $quotes as $posts ) : setup_postdata( $posts );
        ?>  
        <div class="quote_container">

            <em><?php the_content(); ?> - <p><?php the_title(); ?></p></em>
        </div>  
        <?php 
        endforeach;
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
add_shortcode('random_quotes','quotes_shortcode');
```

I have created a wordpress shortcode to show a random quote per day, the content of the quote seems to be displaying fine but the title is incorrect as it is getting the title of the page or post that the shortcode is inserted to.

Comment: Change `$posts->the_title()` to `the_title()`

Comment: also tried that still not displaying correctly

Comment: `$quotes = ( $args );` should not be `$quotes = get_posts( $args );`?

Comment: also done that :( . lemme update the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As in the documentation:

> setup_postdata() **does not** assign the global $post variable so it’s important that you do this yourself. Failure to do so will cause problems with any hooks that use any of the above globals in conjunction with the $post global, as they will refer to separate entities.

So try this:

```
function quotes_shortcode() {
    if ( false === ( $quotes = get_transient( 'random_quote' ) ) ) {
        // It wasn't there, so regenerate the data and save the transient

        global $post; // Calls global $post variable

        $args = array(
         'post_type' => 'quotes',
         'orderby'   => 'rand',
         'fields' => 'id',
         'posts_per_page' => '1'
        );

        $quotes = get_posts( $args );
        //Now we store the array for one day.
        //Just change the last parameter for another timespan in seconds.
        $seconds_until_next_day = strtotime('tomorrow') - time();
        set_transient( 'random_quote', $quotes, MINUTE_IN_SECONDS );
    }

        foreach ( $quotes as $quote ) : 

            $post = $quote; // Set $post global variable to the current post object

            setup_postdata( $post );
        ?>  
        <div class="quote_container">

            <em><?php the_content(); ?> - <p><?php the_title(); ?></p></em>
        </div>  
        <?php 
        endforeach;
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
add_shortcode('random_quotes','quotes_shortcode');
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `<?php echo $post->post_title; ?>` to show correct title.

Comment: Per the [docs on `the_title()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_title/), it seems like the right function to use.

Based on comments on the question, I think they tried `$post->post_title` already

Comment: the_title() is for displaying current page/post title. Jomar Bruto is creating a shortcode that can be used in other page or post. In the previous comment he used plural form, $posts not $post. And it should be used with echo.